# How do I change the whole page background color with each route using React?

Tags: css, reactjs, themes

Im building a react app and I want every route to have a different background color.
But the only way to change the background color of the whole page is by using the * {} tag. Is there some kind of theme library or anything I can do to pass a variable from my routes to the * {} tag to change its background color?

Other solutions would include putting a min-height on my root component but that just feels wrong and I will not do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use this as well

```js
    function App() {
    
      const [color, changeColor] = useState("#282c34");

      document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
      
      return (
        <div>
          <Router>
            <div>
              <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/" onClick={() => changeColor("#282c34")}>
                      Home
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/about/" onClick={() => changeColor("#9c27b0")}>
                      About
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/users/" onClick={() => changeColor("#007bff")}>
                      Users
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Index} />
              <Route path="/about/" component={About} />
              <Route path="/users/" component={Users} />
            </div>
          </Router>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: ah yes i can use `document.body.style.backgroundColor` in any component thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by adding `<style>` tag to the component your `<Route>` redirects to:

```
<style>
    {`body{background-color: red;}`}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state color and pass it to each Route.
This is an exemple to illustrate what i ve told you :

```
function App() {

  const [color, changeColor] = useState("#282c34");
  return (
    <div style={{ background: color }} id="main">
      <Router>
        <div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/" onClick={() => changeColor("#282c34")}>
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/about/" onClick={() => changeColor("#9c27b0")}>
                  About
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/users/" onClick={() => changeColor("#007bff")}>
                  Users
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Index} />
          <Route path="/about/" component={About} />
          <Route path="/users/" component={Users} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes however this only changes the div's background color, not the whole page. So if there isnt alot of content in my page, the background color wont cover the full screen